# Help with setTitle on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a rookie with programming.  I have entered in the following code and the app runs without bugs but crashes when the button is pressed.  The goal is to identify if the button is pressed once or twice.  If it is pressed a third time, it should reset to never being pressed.

buttonTestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface buttonTestViewController : UIViewController {
}

-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

buttonTestViewController.m

```
@implementation buttonTestViewController


-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender{
static int counter;

if (counter == 0) {
    [sender setTitle:@"not answered"];
}else if (counter == 1) {
    [sender setTitle:@"Pressed Once"];
}else if (counter == 2) {
    [sender setTitle:@"Pressed Twice"];
}
counter += 1;

if (counter > 2) {
    counter = 0;
}
}
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I would also like to change the background color of the button when pressed and I continue to get errors if I use setBackgroundColor.  Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize `counter`. It could be any number in the legal range of `int`s with how you have it right now, and it changes every time this method is called.

```
static int counter = 0;
```

Also move that line outside of your method declaration so `counter` isn't reset to 0 every time the method is called. Or use an instance variable instead of a static one. That's all you should need to get this working.

What error do you get when you try to use `setBackgroundColor:`?

**Edit**

Also, if your control is a `UIButton`, `setTitle:` isn't a valid method. Check the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) from Apple. You'd need to do something like:

```
[[sender titleLabel] setText:@"not answered"];
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it should be fine to have the static declaration in the method body.  It should still only be initialized once.

Comment: You could be right. I usually never put them in there for sanity's sake, but I also rarely use statics to begin with. Too lazy to check for sure right now. =)

Comment: Thanks Marc.  It no longer takes a dive.  I was using UIButton with setTitle. However, it doesn't display the new title.  Do I need to create a UILable to display the text?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: `[sender titleLabel]` is the `UILabel` that the button uses to display its text. Are you certain you have everything setup in Interface Builder correctly? Make sure it's not a multi-state button you have setup.

Comment: I am very green at this so I can't say that I am 100% sure that everything is correct in the Interface Builder.  I did connect the Action pressButton to the File's Owner of the buttonTestViewController.xib in the Interface Builder.  The Multiple Touch button in the View screen in the setup is not checked.  Does it sound like I am on the right track.  Again, I really appreciate you time and patients.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track. Keep at it, and read everything Apple provides for you. You'll get it eventually. Good luck!

Comment: ""Also, if your control is a UIButton, setTitle: isn't a valid method. Check the API docs from Apple. You'd need to do something like: [[sender titleLabel] setText:@"not answered"]; ""


Wow!!! so settitle used to work in 5.0 and before but in 5.1 it no longer works so this was really screwing with me. Thanks for pointing this out it solved all my problems.